# Sliding a UIView in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, slide

I'm creating a slidable UIView called "containerView" in each cell of a UITableView. However, when i slide a containerView in a specific cell, all containerViews in all cells slide with it. Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestCell") as! TestTableViewCell
    cell.containerView.frame =  CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width - 100, y:200, width: 225, height: 70)
    cell.containerView.center.x = self.view.frame.size.width - 100
    cell.containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    cell.containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(wasDragged(gestureRecognizer:)))
    cell.containerView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    cell.containerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    gesture.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

and this is my drag function:

```
func wasDragged(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    print("wassss dragggggeeed")
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began || gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        print(gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x)
        let newx = gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x

        if(newx <= self.view.frame.width + 50) && (newx >= self.view.frame.width - 100) {
            gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: newx, y:  gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y)
        }else if (newx > self.view.frame.width + 50){
            gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width + 50, y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y)
        }else if (newx < self.view.frame.width - 100){
            gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width - 100, y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y)
        }

        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0), in: self.view)
    }
}
```

I want each containerView in each cell to be independent of the other. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: did you gave any tag for each view? You can do it via tag and particular tag view will slide.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this code in **cellForRowAt** method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! TestTableViewCell

    cell.containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(wasDragged(gestureRecognizer:)))
    cell.containerView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    cell.containerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    return cell
}
```

and in ***wasDragged(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer)*** method

```
func wasDragged(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let gestureView = gestureRecognizer.view!
    let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)

    // manage translation as per your requirement
    let newx = gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x/10

    if gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {
        // while dragging
        if newx < view.frame.size.width && newx >= view.frame.size.width/2 {
            gestureView.center = CGPoint(x: newx, y:  gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y)
        }
    } else if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
        // when dragging ends
        if newx >= view.frame.size.width {
            gestureView.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width, y:  gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y)
        } else {
            gestureView.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width/2, y:  gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y)
        }
    }
}
```